# AngularJS HTTP POST does not work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, post

I'm just starting to learn AngularJS with NodeJs + mySQL and I'm not really familiar with how express handles POST request from Angular's controller.

**UPDATES**
I'm am able to get POST /login 200 on my cmd now but page does not redirect to **success.html** for some reason. I also get "action on success" meaning the callback was successful?

This is my client side(Angular) code, **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="loginController">
<div class="container">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1 class="welcome text-center" style="text-align:center;">Welcome</h1>

    <div class="card card-container">
    <!--
    <h2 class='login_title text-center'>Login</h2>
    -->
    <hr>

        <form class="form-signin" ng-submit="sub()">

            <p class="input_title">Username:</p>
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="login_box" ng-model="username" required autofocus>
            <p class="input_title">Password</p>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="login_box" ng-model="password" required>
         <br>
         <br>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form><!-- /form -->
    </div><!-- /card-container -->
</div><!-- /container -->

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("loginController", function($scope,$http) {

$scope.sub = function() {

    var data = {
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password,
        body: $scope.body
    };

    $http.post("/login", data).then(function(success){
        console.log('action on success');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('action on error');
    });


}
}
</script>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

And my server side code, **server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var config = require('./config');
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
var passport = require('passport');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-
type, Authorization');
next();
});


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/views/index.html');


});

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
console.log("post here!");
return res.redirect(__dirname +'/app/views/success.html');
});

app.listen(3000,function(err){

if(err){

console.log(err);
}
else{
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
}
});
```

Shouldn't the POST code for server.js run and redirect me to success.html once user click on submit?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error you are getting? does it print any console in browser?

Comment: The application just does not work. Every time I clicked on submits it just refreshes itself

Comment: Use `novalidate` on your form to prevent the refresh from happening. As to why no console log is showing in your JS, it's because in your post request on the server you're not returning a response, so none of the fail/success callbacks are triggered.

Comment: Hi @DragoşPaulMarinescu, I got it to work where I am receiving a fail callbacks now, and receiving a 302 on my cmd prompt but it's not redirecting to the resource. Is my function for POST /login on the server correct for redirecting user to another page?

Comment: res.redirect takes in a route. Pass a url relative to ur home url of /

Comment: @NitishPhanse Does return res.redirect(__dirname + '/app/views/success.html'); not work? I've tried return res.redirect('/views/success.html'); but to no avail